# Is this procedure for $5^{300} \bmod 11$ correct?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

I'm new to modular exponentiation. Is this procecdure correct?

$$5^{300} \bmod 11$$

---

$$5^{1} \bmod 11 = 5\\
5^{2} \bmod 11 = 3\\
5^{4} \bmod 11 = 3^2 \bmod 11 = 9\\
5^{8} \bmod 11 = 9^2\bmod 11 = 4\\
5^{16} \bmod 11 = 4^2 \bmod 11 = 5\\
5^{32} \bmod 11 = 5^2 \bmod 11 = 3$$

---

$$5^{300} = 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 +3 +3 + 3 + 3 +3 +4 + 9$$

Comment: you didn't explain anything, why are you adding all those numbers?

Comment: You were doing well until that last line. What is up with adding all of those numbers?

Comment: Now use $5^{300}=5^{256}\cdot5^{32}\cdot5^8\cdot5^4$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're *almost* there.  Instead of your last line, you want:
$$5^{300} \equiv 5^{4}5^{8}5^{32}5^{256} \pmod{11}$$
Now you replace each of those factors with the modular equivalent you found before (e.g. $5^4\implies 9$)

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 9):

You could also notice $11$ is prime, so by [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) $ 5^{10}\equiv 1 \bmod 11$

from here we get $5^{300}=(5^{10})^{30}\equiv1^{30}\equiv 1 \bmod 11$

Answer (score 0):

I see what you were trying to do with adding the numbers at the end.

Multiply them instead, and take that product $\mod 11$.